# Reproduce the catapult with elastic Angry bird SpriteKit

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit

I want create a slingshot like Angry Bird and my question is how can I create a elastic which follow my sprite (a bird for example) when I load the launched and which hang to my slingshot ?

How can I do that with SpriteKit ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of logic coding you really need to figure out on your own. I will give you something to work with. This is from my personal prototype:

```
-(void)fireRocket
{
if (timesRan <= 0) {
    timesRan++;

}
else
{
    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"rocket" usingBlock: ^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        SKSpriteNode *rocket = (SKSpriteNode *) node;
        [rocket removeFromParent];
        [rocket removeAllActions];
    }];
}

SKSpriteNode * rocket = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"rocket-310663_150"];
rocket.size = CGSizeMake(30, 32);
rocket.name = @"rocket";
rocket.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:16];
rocket.position = CGPointMake(50, 185);




//CGFloat angle = M_PI_4;

CGFloat magnitude = 26;

CGFloat angle = [self angleOfRocketFire];
//CGFloat angle = M_PI_4;



[self addChild:rocket];
[rocket.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(magnitude*cos(angle),
                                              magnitude*sin(angle))];
}



-(CGFloat)angleOfRocketFire
{
__block CGFloat angle;
__block CGPoint handlePosition;

[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"handle" usingBlock: ^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {

    SKSpriteNode *handle = (SKSpriteNode *) node;

    CGFloat xCoord = handle.position.x + (handle.size.width  / 2);
    CGFloat yCoord = handle.position.y + (handle.size.height / 2);

    handlePosition =  CGPointMake(xCoord, yCoord);
}];

[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"rocketLauncher" usingBlock: ^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {

    SKSpriteNode *rocketLauncher = (SKSpriteNode *) node;


    CGFloat xCoord = rocketLauncher.position.x + (rocketLauncher.size.width  / 2);
    CGFloat yCoord = rocketLauncher.position.y + (rocketLauncher.size.height / 2);

    CGPoint launcherPosition =  CGPointMake(xCoord, yCoord);

    CGFloat slope = (handlePosition.y - launcherPosition.y) / (handlePosition.x - launcherPosition.x);

    //angle = atan(slope);
    angle = atan(slope);

    NSLog(@"%f", slope);
}];



return angle;
}
```